# Can I Trust LoadOperation.Completed event

Tags: c#, silverlight, asynchronous, wcf-ria-services

Suppose that we have the code shown below,

```
LoadOperation lop=_dsrvX.Load(_dsrvX.GetUserDetails(userID));
lop.Completed +=(s,a)=>
{
  Debug.WriteLine("Completed but,
           First I load it then I registered Completed evet!");
}
```

I see this type code everywhere so I wonder is it right?

As I know when you call domainService methods this automatically fills domain service object's related EntitySet.

Suppose that LoadOperation(Can be Submit,Invoke ops.) completed rapidly and when I passed to the next line where I register completed event everything has done.Is it possible? It seems hard to achive that but can you give me 100% guarantee?

If you can't guarantee that I'm asking if there is a method of calling **OperationBase** objects manually?

Any comment will be appreciated.

Comment: Use the callback, it's "more" reliable, as @Leo suggests

Comment: Forget the doomsayers... MS knew what they were doing :) A LoadOperation (Submit,Invoke) takes a substantial time to execute in processor terms (we are talking several orders of magnitude greater than the return). The load is spawned on another thread before an immediate return. It is 100% safe you assign the handler after the load call as you are doing. See answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is a crazy world, I would not give 100% guarantee of anything :P - But I do not think it should be a problem. If this bothers you, you can pass the callback as a parameter, like this:

```
_dsrvX.Load(_dsrvX.GetUserDetails(userID), userDetailsCallBack, null);

(...)

void userDetailsCallBack(LoadOperation<UserDetails> op)
{
   //do anything with the results
}
```

or, to simplify even further:

```
_dsrvX.Load(_dsrvX.GetUserDetails(userID), (op)=>
   {
       //do anything with the results  
   }, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

### Yes you can trust it - 100% guaranteed!

If you dig into the code behind the *asynchronous* `Load` method, you will see that it starts up another thread, to do the actual load, then returns immediately.

That separate thread then prepares for a service call, performs the service call, and *eventually* returns the resulting data.

It cannot trigger the Completed event until that is all done and we are talking "a lot" of code to get through, not to mention waiting on a web-service, whereas the return is pretty much instantaneous after the thread was started. i.e. no chance for the other thread to complete and interrupt it.

**There is 0% chance that the load will complete before you add the handler on the next line.**

The usual approach is to provide a callback or anonymous method instead, but your existing code is fine. MS knew what they were doing when the designed it that way :)

*I had this argument with Jon Skeet, on a related question, and his reaction was that you don't know what the `Load` method is doing so it "might" happen faster than the return... My pragmatic answer was that we know exactly what is going on, by design, and it 100% returns before the Load even commences*

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Actually I'm maintaining someone else's code.I coded an AsynTaskLoader class for understanding all my Asyn tasks are completed.It is OperationBase based. You may add many Items on AsynTaskList then register all of theirs completed events and count if all of them finished yet.Its logic of my AsynTaskLoader.Even there is a timeout exist on my WCF RIA Services. I also add Timeout option to my AsynTaskLoader, you may aslo define it. If one of my OperationBase task finished before I register Completed event on AsynTaskLoader class Timeout expires I know Tasks completed never,

Comment: reach count of my TaskList in AsynTaskLoader. I can also cancell all operations depending one of my operation has error. Its optional for each AsynTask. MS knew what to do ok but sometimes I don't know. And I really like Leo's comment "this is a crazy world, I would not give 100% guarantee of anything ". Today I can't reference any webservices in Visual Studio. I removed my antivirus software and closed all my firewalls even It doesn't work. So I can't trust a software 100% anytime :) I didn't give all detais in question for easy reading. Thanks agin for contributing StackOverFlow and answer..